# Magento 2: Facing Error -> Uncaught TypeError: data.some is not a function

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.2.2

I am using `magento version 2.2.2`. From yesterday I suddenly started getting error when I try to add a new product. Spinner continue to move on this page but having this error on console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: data.some is not a function
at findFirst (select.js:71)
at UiClass.clear (select.js:295)
at UiClass.setInitialValue (select.js:309)
at UiClass.setInitialValue (/static/version1527225664/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/utils/wrapper.js:109)
at UiClass.initialize (abstract.js:73)
at UiClass.initialize (/static/version1527225664/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/utils/wrapper.js:109)
at UiClass._super (/static/version1527225664/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/utils/wrapper.js:106)
at UiClass.initialize (select.js:123)
at UiClass.initialize (/static/version1527225664/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/utils/wrapper.js:109)
at new UiClass (/static/version1527225664/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/class.js:49)
```

> See image attached

[image]

Kindly Help me to resolve this issue. Much Appreciated your help, thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Check this, it might be help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45719396/uncaught-typeerror-data-some-is-not-a-function

Comment: I have already seen but not relevant answer

Comment: Try to disable extension one by one to finding issue.